# SSRS value expression of texbox uses an aggregate expression without a scope. Multiple datasets, multiple tables

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I'm building a report that has 2 tables in a page. Each table visible in report based on user check box on top of page.

I am displaying Table1 with expression 
`=IIF(Parameters!With_WithoutUpParm.Value = true, true, false)`
Another table with expression
`=IIF(Parameters!With_WithUpParm.Value = true, false, true)`
This works fine.....
Now I want to display totalrecords count in textbox below the tables. which is `SUM(Count(Fields!ID5_DAYS.Value), "DataSet1")`
`SUM(Count(Fields!ID10_DAYS.Value), "DataSet2")` whenever the table displays..
But I am getting scope out of range for aggregrate functions error is occurred. Can you guys where I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

A quick tip before I get to the meat of your question...  If the parameter is already a boolean, you don't need an `IIF` in the visibility property.  You can just set the visibility equal to `=Parameters!With_WithoutUpParm.Value` and `=NOT Parameters!With_WithoutUpParm.Value`.

For the actual question, it looks like you're declaring the scope in just the `SUM` function.  You'll need to specify the scope in the `COUNT` function, as well.  I'm not entirely sure that you need to specify scope multiple times, but try it with the scope specified in just the `COUNT` and add it to the `SUM` if it doesn't.

```
=SUM(COUNT(Fields!ID5_DAYS.Value, "DataSet1"), "DataSet1")
```

Comment: I tried COUNT(Fields!ID5_DAYS.Value, "DataSet1") It worked.. For displaying the textbox's based on the table displaying, I used the same table expressions for visibility expression.  It worked thanks...

Comment: @anvesh Great, glad I could help.  Don't forget to mark the checkmark below the arrows on my answer to mark it as the correct answer for anyone else with a similar issue.